# Asking about software/tool comparison questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I am talking about the question based on *asking for advice in choosing one of x tools*.

Reason behind this is, users intend to ask questions for finding a tool that will help them do their work. But comparison questions are quite deeper than that situation since **the user already know something about two (or three) tools and asking for a comparison between these tools, expecting a detailed answer comparing the pros and cons of them**.

Looking through this perspective, this kind of questions look more *open to argument* than questions asking a (generally any) tool that will help.

So, is it on-topic to ask comparison questions?

Comment: I missed that question.